# Where to install mininet

Tags: debian, software-installation, packaging, fhs

I read some posts and parts of FHS to understand which directory I should install packages in. As far as I could understand `/opt` is for independent packages and `/usr/local` is for packages that are not maintained by distro repo's.

I want to install a network emulator called "mininet" on my Debian wheezy, so that all users can use it. It has an install.sh script which installs both types of packages: maintained by repo & not maintained by repo.
As the first step of the installation I can indicate where I want my base directory to be. Now my question is which directory I should indicate as the base directory?
should it be:
"`/usr/local`", "`/usr/local/mininet`", "`/usr/local/bin`", "`/usr/local/bin/mininet`", "`/opt`" or some other directory?

I would appreciate if you could explain your answer too 
Thank you.

EDIT: Should I specify the name of the package in the path like we do when installing in `/opt` (e.g. `/usr/local/mininet/`) or I shouldn't?

Answer (score 0):

If the base directory you mean is used for the `--prefix` option of `./configure` or `make`, it should be `/usr/local`.

This way, the software can be installed into the subdirectories of `/usr/local`, like
`/usr/local/bin`, `/usr/local/lib/mininet` and `/usr/local/man`.

Comment: I did that once and I realized that the installer has created some files and directories outside of `/usr/local/bin` in `/usr/local/...`. is that compliant with FHS?

Comment: The FHS explicitly does not specify anything under `/usr/local` - so it's compliant. To me, it makes sense to use a structure like under `/usr`.

Answer (score 0):

for mininet, probably the best way to install it is trying to use the ubuntu packages (option three at http://mininet.org/download/). This will put the package in `/usr` but more than that *will allow you to uninstall the package, even in the case you are doing an upgrade, using `apt-get`*, without leaving litter around your system.

Otherwise I suggest you to install it in `/opt/mininet` or something. Avoid `/usr/local` if possible, because all package will mix together and you won't be able to sort which file is related to which package should you want to remove something.

Comment: If you want the binaries or man pages to be usable by everyone you can manually put symlinks into `/usr/local/...` pointing to `/opt/mininet/...`.
This would still let you distinguish which files are related to mininet and which ones aren't.